# How to run Scheffe test with Anova from 'car' package in R

Tags: r, anova, desctools

I am using Anova function from 'car' package in R to do 3 - way split plot analysis in R.

I know there is a function ScheffeTest in the package 'DescTools' to run Scheffe Test for 'aov' function.

My question is, how could I run Scheffe test for the result of Anova function?

Comment: I've looked into that, but there's no fast solution to extend the function ScheffeTest to the Anova object, as it does not return enough information. Why not using aov? (an example would by the way be helpful...)

Comment: Hi @AndriSignorell, thank you very much for your comment. I want to change the default contrast in ScheffeTest with aov. Is it possible?

Comment: Contrasts can be defined quite flexible. Post an example explaining your task.